# What is the most efficient way update multiple rows in a database and log it?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am working on making a relatively simple inventory system in which data is stored and updated with MySQL with Python connected to it. When adding to stock, an end user would input values into an interface and associate a purchase ticket number with that transaction. A log would then indicate that purchase ticket x added units to stock.

In a single purchase ticket, several items in stock may be increased, i.e. several rows within the stock table will need to be updated per purchase ticket.

However, I am having trouble conceptualizing an efficient way of updating multiple rows while still associating the purchase ticket number with the transaction. I was going to use a simple UPDATE statement, but can't figure out how to link the ticket number.

I was considering making a table for purchase tickets, but figured it would be more efficient to just increment stock with UPDATEs alone, but I appear to be wrong. Was going to use something like:

```sql
UPDATE stock SET count + x WHERE id = y;
```

Where x is how much the stock is being incremented by, and y is the specific product's unique ID.

TL;DR is there any efficient way to update multiple rows in a single column while also associating a user-inputted number with that transaction?

Comment: I think it make sense to have a purchase ticket log which record all transaction records with constraint on stock ids so for one purchase, multiple insertion will happen to the log keeper, eg transaction x affected stock a and b, then insert x,a and another insertion x,b also you may wanna include the amount as another column

Answer (score 0):

Don’t update. Updates are slow because the transaction has to seek out each row to be updated. Just append to the end of the table. Then use the Output clause so you have access to what got inserted. Finally you can join to those results that will include the primary keys and log those keys in another table.

Comment: Wouldn't appending to the end of the table cause an error with inserting a duplicate primary key value? Or are you saying that the keys that were failed to be inserted would be logged and stored in another table? Can you clarify this for me?

Comment: Your table should be set up to have an identity column that auto increments as the primary key.